# Creating associative magic squares z3 python

Tags: z3py

So Im working with magic squares. I've created conditions for a regular magic square. Now I need to add the constraints to make it associative.

I'm using the z3 python module.
To be associative, the sum of the opposite numbers need to be equal to the same number 't'. the sum of all the rows and columns and diagonals need to be equal to this number t as well. So I'm struggling with accessing the numbers individually from each list in the list of lists.

[image]

For example, these are the constraints I have for a regular magic square:

```
t = Int('t')
  Square = [ [ Int("x_%s_%s" % (i+1, j+1)) for j in range(n) ] for i in range(n) ]  
  distinct = [ Distinct([ Square[i][j] for i in range(n) for j in range(n) ]) ]
  cell = [ And(1 <= Square[i][j], Square[i][j] <= n**2) for i in range(n) for j in range(n) ]
  row = [(sum(Square[i]) == t) for i in range(n)]
  col = [(sum([Square[j][i] for j in range(n)]) == t) for i in range(n)]
  firstDiagonal = [ (sum([Square[i][i]  for i in range(n)]) == t) ]
  secondDiagonal = [ (sum([Square[n-i-1][i] for i in range(n)]) == t) ]
```

So how do I associative conditions?

Comment: There's no question here

Comment: There's no python or z3 here. Please don't spam irrelevant tags

Comment: I accidentally left something out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I amended your model and added associative constraints:

```
from z3 import *

def ShowSquare(model, square, rows, cols):
    print()
    print("Square")
    for row in range(rows):
        s = ""
        for col in range(cols):
            s = s + str(model.eval(square[row][col])).ljust(4)
        print(s)

s = Solver()

n = 3
t = Int('t')
 
magicSquare = [ [ Int("x_%s_%s" % (i+1, j+1)) for j in range(n) ] for i in range(n) ]  
distinctConstraints = [ Distinct([ magicSquare[i][j] for i in range(n) for j in range(n) ]) ]
cellConstraints = [ And(1 <= magicSquare[i][j], magicSquare[i][j] <= n**2) for i in range(n) for j in range(n) ]
rowConstraints = [(sum(magicSquare[i]) == t) for i in range(n)]
colConstraints = [(sum([magicSquare[j][i] for j in range(n)]) == t) for i in range(n)]
firstDiagConstraints = [ (sum([magicSquare[i][i]  for i in range(n)]) == t) ]
secondDiagConstraints = [ (sum([magicSquare[n-i-1][i] for i in range(n)]) == t) ]

AssocSum = Int('AssocSum')
assocRowConstraints = [((magicSquare[0][i] + magicSquare[n-1][n-i-1]) == AssocSum) for i in range(n) ] 
assocColConstraints = [((magicSquare[i][0] + magicSquare[n-i-1][n-1]) == AssocSum) for i in range(1, n-1) ] 

# performance tweak
# the magic sum is known in advance
s.add(2*t == n*(n*n+1))

s.add(distinctConstraints)
s.add(cellConstraints)
s.add(rowConstraints)
s.add(colConstraints)
s.add(firstDiagConstraints)
s.add(secondDiagConstraints)
s.add(assocRowConstraints)
s.add(assocColConstraints)
print(s.check())
model = s.model()
print("magic sum %s" % model.eval(t))
print("assoc sum %s" % model.eval(AssocSum))
ShowSquare(model, magicSquare, n, n)
```

The result is a transposed version of the [Lo Shu Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lo_Shu_Square) linked in the question:

```
sat
magic sum 15
assoc sum 10

Square
4   3   8   
9   5   1   
2   7   6
```

For `n=5`, a solution is:

```
magic sum 65
assoc sum 26

Square
8   7   12  15  23  
17  20  22  1   5   
16  2   13  24  10  
21  25  4   6   9   
3   11  14  19  18
```

Comment: That is very helpful thank you. Though could you please explain this:                     
  s.add(2*t == n*(n*n+1)) and how it weaks the performance? I'm not quite sure what this does.

Comment: The magic sum times `n` must be equal to the sum of all `n²` cells. The sum of all numbers from `1` to `n²` is `n²/2(n²+1)`. This leads to `2t == n*(n²+1)` avoiding division and rounding. A fixed variable reduces the search space of *Z3* and thus speeds up the solving process. One could declare `t` to be a constant rather than an `Int` decision variable. I f you consider this answer helpful, feel free to *accept* it by hitting the arrow on the left side of the answer.